# 3 winding transformer working principle

Tags: transformer

What is the difference in this two different 3-winding transformer ?

[image]

[image]

Will the second one work ? Why or why not ?

I am really confused with both this circuit. Please help me with this.

Comment: Think about where the magnetic flux from where the mutual inductance would occur.

Comment: B to R will have a strange coupling due to flux distribution.

Comment: @KingDuken, I am not able to figure that out. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Picture it this way--you want the flux from one coil to go through (at least one of) the other two.  R and Y are inextricably coupled in the second configuration--they're part of the same loop--but the flux from B can complete its circuit without going through R or Y.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis, what will be the secondary output voltage then when a 100V rms is applied to primary ? Will it still be 200 V rms or it will be 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider what happens when you think about Y and R phases: -

[image]

Basically R and Y phases share the same magnetic part of the core and hence any voltage or phase difference between them is going to act like shorted turns.

Comment: What happens if a balanced voltage source is applied on the primary side ? Will the secondary side voltages will be balanced and  twice the value?

Comment: @Nikhil: There is no "primary side" indicated on your sketch. Use 'R', 'B' or 'Y' instead of 'primary' so that we know which winding you are referring to.

Comment: @Transistor, this question was asked to me in an interview. They gave this configuration and asked what will be the secondary voltage if 100V rms is applied to the primary side. I had no clue what to say. I posted it here so you guys can show throw some light on this.

Comment: It looks like an incorrectly wound 3-phase transformer. I would have asked which is the primary.

Comment: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6sMbE6k_33E/U2C-TQQL0qI/AAAAAAAAAyw/jDA4wik0kko/s1600/three+phase+transformer+core+type.png

Comment: The above link is the proper way to wound 3 winding core type transformer. But they changed it to like the one I drew in the question. Primary is the LV winding where they are giving a balanced supply. Will the HV winding have balanced output. Will that work as a normal config? Why or why not ?

Comment: Yes, the secondary (HV) will have a balanced output for a balanced primary voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka, but why we don't use this configuration ? What is the problem with this then ?

Comment: Can you be clear about the configuration you are asking about. The one in the link 4 comments up is fine to use.